# Can someone please explain why the answer is 6?

Tags: java

```
private int field;

public void f(int n) {
    n = n + field;
    field = field + n;
    n = n + 2; 
}

public void g() {
    field = 2;
    f(field); 
}
```

What would be the final value of field after invoking `g()`? I know the answer is 6 but could someone please explain why?

Comment: What's unclear about it?

Comment: What happens when you "run it on your brain computer"? Go line by line substituting in the values. Note that reassignment to `n` (without assigning the result of such) has *no effect* on `field`.

Comment: i Just don't know why the final value equals to 6. Could you explain why please if you can? Thanks

Comment: Because you wrote code to make it 6

Comment: Show your "brain computer" work at each step.

Comment: field is a global variable. n is a local variable. Only the value of 'field' is copied to the local variable 'n' and therefore when the value of 'n' is changed, the value of 'field' will not be changed.. You have to change the value of 'field' to change its value..

Answer (score 7):

you can expand your code to something like this:

```
field = 2;         //               field == 2
int n = field;     // n == 2;       field == 2
n = n + field;     // n = 2+2 == 4; field == 2
field = field + n; // n == 4;       field = 2+4 == 6
n = n + 2;         // n = 4+2 == 6; field == 6
```

final values:

```
field == 6
n == 6
```

NOTE: `a = b` means that only value of `b` stored/copied into `a`, but `a` and `b` are two different variables which are not related to each other

Answer (score 1):

@Lashane has give you an answer but I try to explain it as simple as I can.
In method *g()* you:

1. set variable '**field**' as 2.
2. Then call method *f*. Note that the '**field**' is a class variable and a parameter of method *f(int n)*. So at start of method *f* both variables 'n' and 'field' are set as 2.

Then the calculations (included in method *f*) are clear:

```
 n = n + field; // n = 2 + 2 == 4
 field = field + n; // field = 2 + 4
 n = n + 2; // n = 4 + 2 == 6
```